# click to append button and again to back.?

Tags: javascript, jquery

unable to append functionally written code.
Like if a button clicked it will disable and append to div and if again clicked inside div it will hide and again enable the parent button.

Logic am using comparing innerHtml value. Now problem comes like having same innerHtml value.
Please help in this.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.shadowbutton')).forEach(
(button)=>{
    button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        let text = e.target.innerHTML;
        let text1 = e.target.innerText;
    console.log(button)
    backbutton();
        this.disabled = true;
        $(this).addClass('disable');
        $('<button class="shadowbutton">' + text + "</button>").appendTo(dottedbox);
    })
}
)


function backbutton() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        let dbutton = document.querySelectorAll('.dotted-box .shadowbutton');
        let parent = document.querySelectorAll('.dotted-box');
        if ( $(parent).children().length > 0 ) {
            dbutton.forEach(
                (button)=>{
                    button.addEventListener("click", (e)=> {
            console.log(button)
                        let parent = e.target.parentElement;
                        let parentdiv = document.querySelectorAll('.disable');
                        let dgfg = e.target
                        $(dgfg).removeAttr('disabled');
                        parentdiv.forEach(
                            (button)=>{
                                if(e.target.innerHTML == button.innerHTML){
                                    $(button).first().removeAttr('disabled');
                                    $(button).first().removeClass('disable');
                                }
                                else{
                                    //console.log(button)
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        parent.removeChild(e.target);
                    })
                }
            )
    }   
    },100)
}
```

Problem is while clicking <p> it is enabling both <p> button. it should enable first button only.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shanthece/cfzcnn0b/3/)

Comment: Could you please try to improve the wording? I have a very hard time understanding what you mean by "unable to append functionally written code." To me it sounds like you want to add javascript code dynamically, but I get the feeling you mean something else.

Comment: Small side note, if `button` is a single element, you do not have to use `first()` in `$(button).first()` as the jQuery will only contain a single element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store you current clicked button in your new created button as reference variable and you can get same button new created button click using `event.target`

**DEMO**

```js
let dottedbox = document.querySelector('.dotted-box');

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.shadowbutton')).forEach(button => {button.addEventListener("click",onButtonClick)})

function onButtonClick(e) {

  let text = e.target.innerHTML;
  this.disabled = true;
  $(this).addClass('disable');
  let btn = $('<button class="shadowbutton">' + text + "</button>");
  btn.on("click", (e) => {
    let parent = e.target.parentElement;
    let parentdiv = document.querySelectorAll('.disable');
    let buttton = $(e.target.pBtn);
    //console.log(e.target)
    buttton.removeAttr('disabled');
    buttton.removeClass('disable');
    e.target.remove();
  });
  btn[0].pBtn = e.target;
  btn.appendTo(dottedbox);
}
```

```css
.dotted-box {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  min-height: 70px;
  margin: 2rem 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;/p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;/p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">Hi all.!</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">Hello all.!</button>
</div>
<div class="dotted-box">
</div>
```

---

You can also implement same as using jQuery with less code

**DEMO**

```js
$('.shadowbutton').on('click', function() {
  let button = $(this);
  button.prop('disabled', true).addClass('disable');
  let newbtn = $(`<button class="shadowbutton">${button.html()}</button>`);
  newbtn[0].pBtn = this;
  newbtn.appendTo($('.dotted-box')).on("click",newButtonClick);
});

function newButtonClick() {
  let button = $(this);
  let pButtton = $(button[0].pBtn);
  pButtton.prop('disabled',false).removeClass('disable');
  button.remove();
}
```

```css
.dotted-box {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  min-height: 70px;
  margin: 2rem 0;

}
.shadowbutton{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;/p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;/p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">&lt;p&gt;</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">Hi all.!</button>
  <button class="shadowbutton">Hello all.!</button>
</div>
<div class="dotted-box">
</div>
```

Comment: simple and neat